# Expiration of autoconfig IPv4 addresses on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, dhcp

This morning I lost remote access to a Windows 7 computer because the machine decided to use an autoconfiguration IPv4 address (169.254.154.30) instead of it's DHCP reservation. I've left it alone for over 3 hours but it remains unreachable.

Since the DHCP server is displaced from this machine by a WDS WiFi link and I'm using shortish (30m) lease times, it's believable that the server was temporarily unavailable. However, I'm able to login to both devices that serve the WDS link and I can see other devices on the network (just not the Windows machine) so I know the DHCP server is available generally.

While I can't find specific details on Windows' behavior, this [source](https://www.lifewire.com/automatic-private-internet-protocol-addressing-816437) claims that it should recover a DHCP address (emphasis mine):

> When the DHCP process fails, Windows automatically allocates an IP
>   address from the private range 169.254.0.1 to 169.254.255.254. Using
>   ARP, clients verify the chosen APIPA address is unique on the network
>   before deciding to use it. **Clients then continue checking back with
>   the DHCP server at a periodic interval (usually 5 minutes) and update
>   their addresses automatically when the DHCP server is again able to
>   service requests.**

Clearly that's not the case, though. I've managed to solve this remotely by rebooting the bridge device serving the Windows computer. Not very ideal.

Is there some way to beat Windows into giving up autoconfig addresses in favor of DHCP? And to force it into watching for the DHCP server to become available?

Comment: Why is your DHCP lease time so short? The other option is change your DHCP range, and put a static IP on that computer outside that range.

Comment: Good question.. while increasing the DHCP lease time would certainly reduce the prob of Windows 'falling back' to autoconfig, it fails to resolve the particular situation I'm asking about. Thanks

Comment: From [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/958336/a-computer-loses-its-dhcp-ip-address-if-a-dhcp-server-is-not-available) TechNet article, maybe you can try this:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` create a DWORD `DontPingGateway` and set it to `1`. But to avoid this issue in general, why not change the DHCP scope, and just set the IP for that machine to something outside that scope?